# The content not wrapped in paragraph tags with get_page_by_title()

Tags: theme-development, pages, theme-options

I am using `$page = get_page_by_title('name')`; to get the contents of a page.  When I echo `$page->post_content;` none of the content is wrapped in p tags like it is when run threw the normal wordpress loop using `the_content(`). Is there a different way I should get this data so it will contain the proper tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the content filters to `$page->post_content` like so:

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content);
```